# Covariance Question

Tags: statistics, covariance

Can anyone show me what Cov(A, (X_1 + X_2)) is?

I'm hoping its Cov(A, X_1) + Cov(A, X_2), is it possible?

/Confused student.

Comment: Is $A$ a constant ?

Comment: No it is not a constant.

Comment: Non of them are

Comment: I believe Covariance is a scalar product over the vector space of centered random variable.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, What I'm trying to prove is that for Z = X_1 + X_2. E(AZ) = E(A(X_1 + X_2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\begin{align} Cov(A, X_1 + X_2) &= E(A(X_1 + X_2)) - E(A)E(X_1 +X_2)  \\&= E(A X_1) - E(A)E(X_1) + E(A X_2) - E(A)E(X_2) \\&= Cov(A, X_1) + Cov(A, X_2)\end{align}$$